# what is the meaning of "sufficiently comparable"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

> firms will not disclose sufficient, or sufficiently comparable,
>   information unless they are required to do so

Could you kindly let me know what "sufficiently comparable" means in the sentence I quoted above?

I can't imagine what "sufficiently comparable" can mean in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it means that the recipient is given enough information to be able to be compared. For example, how much water or electricity they use annually.

Comment: Yes; information with which a reasonable comparison can be made.